# Show JSON as JSON in browser

Tags: javascript, json, middleware

I am building middleware for an API in Javascript. 
I try to show my Javascript in JSON, but I show only the raw text.
I need the JSON format for the external application.

Example code:

```
var obj = new Object();
   obj.name = "Raj";
   obj.age  = 32;
   obj.married = false;
   var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);
   console.log(jsonString);
   document.getElementById("test").innerText = jsonString;
```

What I get:

[image: pic: What I get now]

What I want:

[image: pic: What I want]

I hope that somebody can help me :)

Comment: This chrome extension makes it print out pretty JSON, which makes development much nicer: https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter

Answer (score -1):

use `JSON.stringify(obj,null,2)`
where 2 is the indentation size

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'bar',
};
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj,null,2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? :/

Comment: maybe because `document.write` is deprecated. Anyway that's useful for a quick POC

Comment: Or because he wanted to format them with colors and every answer that isn't respecting it is not "worth for his attention"

Comment: It's not OP, he doesn't have the required 125 rep to downvote